# Is looping over the two pandas dataframe is the best approach if you have thousands of rows in the dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am trying to merge multiple tables (in the form of pandas data frame) using python loops (two circles in the image). Table 1 has around 10000 rows that need to be matched and merged with the rows of table 2. Table 2 is redundant and one row of table 1 can have multiple matches (for instance just one row of table 1 could end up as 1000 rows in table 3). Table 3 results from step 1 and table 5 results from step 2.

Every row of table 3 has to be matched with rows of Table 4, which is again in the form of a pandas data frame. The final results file could go up to millions of rows. This whole process is very time-consuming and takes multiple days. I am trying to reduce the run time somehow and I have tried different methods of looping within python and managed to improve the runtime by 10% by using vectorized operation in step one and dictionary-based loop in step 2. I was wondering if there are other methods using which I could further improve the run time. For example, using numba or any other way? Multiprocessing helps but I also don't want to eat up all my memory.

Also, final file writing also takes a lot of time as it's a single-threaded operation.

Here is the code and sample data files:
https://github.com/JstRoRR/test

With one row of table1 query you can get 3000 entries in table3. I have also added top 100 entries from table4. In total it contains 58 million rows. Since I cant share the table4 contents (its a big sqlite database), you wont be able to run the complete code but atleast the example files I have added to the repository will guide you to see the issue. Offcourse the code is running but I need some advice on how I can reduce the run time?

I appreciate any suggestions you might have on this issue.[image]

Comment: Have you read and tried [the section on merging in the Pandas user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)? It looks like the correct set of left/right/inner/outer joins should already get what you want.

Comment: I am using loops because the tables neither have the same columns nor the same dimensions. Can I still use merging or concatenating functions? I should have mentioned this in the figure. The script merges the tables based on the values in table 1 being smaller/larger in one of the columns in table 2.

Comment: That definitely makes a difference, *in particular* the smaller/larger part. Better update your question, since that is important information.

Comment: It helps if you provide an actual small example of the different steps. Possibly like a 5 or 10-row long table 1, a 3-row long table 2, the result of that merge, etc. The shorter, the better, but it will have to be complete (so include both matching and non-matching items).

Comment: You should also specify the actual size of the input tables. Right now, only the size for table 1 is mentioned.

Comment: So, for the first step, for example, I can imagine doing a full outer row, then filtering by comparing two relevant columns of the resulting table. By using only a few relevant columns (the ones to compare, and the index columns of each table) and not all columns of both tables, you can limit the amount of memory. Once filtered, you can use the indices for tables 1 and 2 that are in the resulting table to grab and match the actual data for tables 1 and 2.

Comment: NB: if you do add some example dataframes to your question, preferably create them as code, so that people who want to answer your question, can copy-paste the code of the example dataset and use that as base for their answer. This is in contrast to e.g. a nicely formatted (Markdown) table that some people do, but which is hard to copy-paste as starting point for an answer

Comment: @9769953 Hi Thanks for your comments. I have added some files and the complete code. Hope this helps.

Comment: @9769953 Also I have added the full results output from a single row of table 1.